# Unsubscribe module issue

Tags: 7

I installed the [Unsubscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/unsubscribe) module. I have also set this module's permissions for both authenticated and anonymous user.

[image: enter imag].

Now the unsubscribe checkbox is appearing on the edit account form, but not yet on the user register form, where I want it to appear too.

Is there a way to do so? As an alternative, do you know any other module that provides a similar function/feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bugreport for unsubscribe module, and bugreports belongs to appropriate issue queue, not here.

Comment: Can you further edit / enhance the question to explain WHY you would want such unsubscribe to appear on the user registration form? I find it strange that on that specific form you would want to provide such option. I.e.: a registration request that should NOT be trigger some type of notify to the registered user (either the request is approved, or being reviewed by an admin). I trust you have a good reason for it, so after we understand those reasons better, we can suggest "other modules" that would fit what you actually want to achieve. OK?

Comment: Re comment from @Mołot : I have no rep to vote as you suggested, but I'm pretty sure this is not some type of bug. Instead more like a howto question, no? If you disagree, can you explain why you think it is about some bug please?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens for me it looked like "option was expected / should be displayed there, but isn't" - and that would be a bugreport or feature request. If it would read like "there should be a way to decide where option is displayed, so where is it?", it would be a bit different matter. But most modules don't provide "configuration of configuration", so that seemed unlikely. I accept that I might be wrong. That's why it requires 4 other people (or one moderator) to agree with me for my vote to make any difference.

Comment: Thank you @Mołot for clarifying, that explains your viewpoint (and possible close voting). I just suggested an edit of the question, to reflect how "I" now understand the question (also via the extra comments added by the OPer). I won't earn any +2 rep anymore for edits, but still hope my "suggestion" gets approved ... would be nice if Molot would be one of the approvers ...! curiousity: is there any feature like "withdraw to close suggestion"?

Answer (score 0):

### Using module Unsubscribe

About the "not appearing in fields of user register form" in the question: it seems to me that the [unsubscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/unsubscribe) module ***might*** just be working as designed, and implemented. From its project page (I added some markup here):

> The module design is very basic. When a user unsubscribes, they are added to an "unsubscribe list," which is stored in the database. Whenever Drupal sends mail, the unsubscribe module will check to see if the recipient is on the unsubscribe list. If so, the email is blocked. **You can exempt specific modules from this blocking via the configuration page.** You can also use hooks to alter exemptions, or override the blocking.
>
> **Emails sent by the system and user modules are currently exempt by default**.

From the question it is not clear to me what you have done regarding the "exempts" (on the module's configuration page). If nothing yet, then that might be the explanation for why it is not appearing on the user register form, no?

### Using some other module

As per your "any other module that provides a similar function/feature": it appears to me that the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module should be worth considering, possibly combined with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module.

If you're not familiar enough with these 2 modules, then I suggest to review this great introduction to the Rules module: [Rules for admin notifications, Part 1: New user registrations](http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/rules-admin-notifications-part-1-new-user-registrations). Maybe also the related [Rules for admin notifications, Part 2: New comments and content](http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/rules-admin-notifications-part-2-new-comments-and-content).